# EF Core Data is Null

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, xunit

Most of the answers on this state that the DbSet on the context must be a property. However that does not seem to be the case in this instance since the DbSet of this context is a property. Here is the sample code that I can use to recreate the problem. Please advise.

### Here is the code:

DbContext

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Dal
{
    public class SampleContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Model.ItemCode> ItemCodes { get; set; }

        public SampleContext(DbContextOptions<SampleContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new Mapping.ItemCodeConfiguration());
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Model.ItemCode>> GetCodesByGroup(int group)
        {
            return await ItemCodes.Where(g => g.GroupId == group).ToListAsync();
        }

    }
}
```

Model

```
namespace Dal.Model
{
    public class ItemCode
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public int KcId { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public int GroupId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Data Mapping

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

namespace Dal.Mapping
{
    public class ItemCodeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Model.ItemCode>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Model.ItemCode> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(b => b.Id);
            builder.Property(b => b.Description)
                .HasColumnName("Description")
                .HasColumnType("nvarchar(255)")
                .IsRequired();
            builder.Property(b => b.Code)
                .HasColumnName("Code")
                .IsRequired();
            builder.Property(b => b.KcId)
                .HasColumnName("KcId");
            builder.Property(b => b.Quantity)
                .HasColumnName("Quantity");
            builder.Property(b => b.GroupId)
                .HasColumnName("GroupId")
                .IsRequired();
            builder.Property(b => b.CategoryId)
                .HasColumnName("CategoryId")
                .IsRequired();
            builder.ToTable("ItemCode", "lookup");
        }
    }
}
```

Test Class

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Xunit;

namespace Dal.Test
{
    public class DataTest
    {
        readonly SampleContext context;
        public DataTest()
        {
            var testContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SampleContext>();
            testContextOptions.UseSqlServer(@"Server=localServerName;Database=SampleAppDb;User Id=SampleUser;Password=sampleUser!Password");
            testContextOptions.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
            context = new SampleContext(testContextOptions.Options);
        }


        [Fact]
        public async void Test1()
        {
            var codes = await context.GetCodesByGroup(1);
            Assert.NotNull(codes);
            Assert.NotEmpty(codes);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which assertion is failing? `GetCodesByGroup` should never return `null`, only empty collection or throw an exception fi something else is wrong.

Comment: Did you populate your database with data having GroupId = 1

Comment: @Markuzy Yes, the database is populated with both categories and groups, and there is a group with the ID 1.

Comment: @Fabio the GetCodesByGroup is returning the Data is null error. And I have no idea why. It has data and relational data. I can run the query in SSMS and it runs fine.

Comment: Can you explain what _returning the Data is null error_ mean? There are no such exception in .NET. Can you point on the line which raises this error?

Comment: The full error is:
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException : Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
The error occurs after this line:
var codes = await context.GetCodesByGroup(1);

Comment: And here is the SQL EF generates (note this sql can be run in SSMS while logged in under the same user as the connection string):
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [i].[Id], [i].[CategoryId], [i].[Code], [i].[Description], [i].[GroupId], [i].[KcId], [i].[Quantity]
FROM [lookup].[ItemCode] AS [i]
WHERE [i].[GroupId] = @__group_0',N'@__group_0 int',@__group_0=1

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer, was a dumb mistake. The mistake was that there are nullable int columns but the properties are not nullable.
Corrected class:

```
namespace Dal.Model
{
    public class ItemCode
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int? Quantity { get; set; }
        public int? KcId { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public int GroupId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: this pointed me in the right direction, thanks!  I had a property that was an int, but it was nullable in the database, so i changed the property to int? and it worked.  The issue is the error doesn't tell you much, it would be nice if the error said Data is null on column x. Maybe it will be fixed in later versions

Comment: I had the same issue with some string properties that were annotated with [required]. upon reading them if they contained nulls I got errors

Comment: Exactly the answer I needed. Thanks.